# How to know photo resolution after camera intent in onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera

Greeting

I have done a camera intent, passing the file parameter to get the full sized image, also I have a function to scale the image and set it in the UI.

How ever, I want to know the resolution with which the user took the photo. Is there anyway to know the resolution user choose?

I want to know this cause my app is crashing in poor hardware devises with hiqh quality resolution. Any photo above 2M pixels will crash older phones.

I know the real solution is to improve performance of JAVA memory in overall application. But this will be a quickfix and I will see the other later. Also, 1.something M pixel for photo is enough. Is just part of a checklist that doesnt need to be in bether quality.

Is there anyway to know the resolution the camera used?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Thanks everybody for your answers but I have to admit, I neglict mi explanation.
Another reason why I want to simply get the resolution is cause the app also transform the URI path in to a content path, so if the photo has too much quality for the phone to handle it, its crash. I only want to warn the user if the resolution is too high, so how could I know every appropiate resolution for every phone, instead of it I just catch the error "java.langOutOfMemory" and that will warn the user. Like this:

```
try {
 //here is my method to convert uri path to content
} catch (OutOfMemoryError outOfMemoryError) {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please lower photo resolution", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.show();

                        }
```

Comment: Use `BitmapFactory` to examine the image, using [`inJustDecodeBounds` to only get you the size and bit depth info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds).

Comment: You stop the crashing you should be applying insampling size factor

Comment: Yes, but if I rescale the image I would have to create also another file to be converted from the uri path to the content path?

Answer (score 3):

You can cast the result to a Bitmap:

```
  Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data.getData().getPath());
```

then you can get the resolution like this:

```
  temp.getWidth();
  temp.getHeight();
```

or you could do this:

```
  BitmapFactory.Options temp = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  temp.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, temp);

  int width = temp.outWidth;
  int height = temp.outHeight;
```